# Disable creation of Service Provider and Role when generating keys for application in WSO2 API Manager 1.10.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

In WSO2 API Manager 1.10.0 (recently upgraded from 1.8.0) in identity-server part, we noticed a new feature that whenever new keys are generated for an application a corresponding service provider and role is created. Since we have a lot of users creating a lot of applications, this quickly fills up our registry with new service providers and roles.

We can't find a way to disable this behavior and we have no use for this functionality.

Anyone knows how to disable it if possible? :) Also, if there's a good explanation out there for this functionality?

Comment: Are you using WSO2 Identity Server as Key Manager?

Comment: No, but we're using the identity parts of the API Manager product. We've split up the product to have several gateway nodes, key manager, publisher & store nodes separately. It's the Store node where users signup and where this behavior shows up.

Comment: What's the role and service provider name created? Also, do you see this behaviour when generating clientId, client Secret?

Comment: Service provider name: <username>_<ApplicationName>_PRODUCTION, Role name: Application/<username>_<ApplicationName>_PRODUCTION. And yes, it's when generating initial clientId and clientSecret.